# Sending a private Teams message within Linux

Tags: linux, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to send a private message in Teams using the Linux command line or Linux app? Now it's well known how to send to a channel using a curl command. However, I require to send a Teams private message to an individual programmatically? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using deep links to achieve some automation programmatically. https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=gaurav.kumar@xxx.com&message=Hi%20folks%2C%20kicking%20off%20a%20chat%20about%20our%20meeting%20tomorrow

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to do this, but instead of controlling the Teams client directly, use the Microsoft Graph API - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Specifically, you'd want to use the "Delegation" security option, to send the message as if it was coming from you personally.